# LocalStrategy function never called

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have tried to setup a simple local strategy authentification with express4 / passportjs, but the authenticate function is never called : 
here's my code

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
app.use(compress());  
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

/*  AUTHENTIFICATION */

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) { //THIS FUNCTION IS NEVER CALLED
    console.log("Local strategy");
  }
));


app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log("user : ", req.body.username);
    console.log("password : ", req.body.password);
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                     failureRedirect: '/login' })
});

/*  !AUTHENTIFICATION */

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'controllers')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'modules')));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

When i send a post request in /login, i see in the logs the username and password but the `password.authentificate` method doesnt do anything.
It should call the `LocalStrategy` function and console.log('strategy') but it doesn't.

Does someone know how to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: may be you are having success/failure redirect and your console is refreshing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`authenticate()'s function signature is standard Connect middleware` from [here](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/).

So reference of `req, res, next` should be passed

So you can use it either as route middleware

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                               failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

Or

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                 failureRedirect: '/login' })(req, res, next);
});
```